# sort using lodash key value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object array objects

```
 [
      {

        "id": "1",
        "images": [
          {
            "filename": "some image name",
            "type": "gallery"
          },
          {
            "filename": "some image name",
            "type": "main"
          },
      {
       "filename": "some image name",
       "type": "gallery"
          }

        ]
      },
      {

        "id": "2",
        "images": [
          {
            "filename": "some image name",
            "type": "gallery"
          },
          {
            "filename": "some image name",
            "type": "main"
          },
          {
            "filename": "some image name",
            "type": "gallery"
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
```

i want to change to make the "type" : "main" first for every object in the array.

**I want to reach this :**

```
[
  {

    "id": "1",
    "images": [
      {
        "filename": "some image name",
        "type": "main"
      },
      {
        "filename": "some image name",
        "type": "gallery"
      },
      {
       "filename": "some image name",
       "type": "gallery"
          }
    ]
  },
  {

    "id": "2",
    "images": [
      {
        "filename": "some image name",
        "type": "main"
      },
      {
        "filename": "some image name",
        "type": "gallery"
      },
      {
       "filename": "some image name",
       "type": "gallery"
          }

    ]
  }
]
```

for every object only one of the images can be main and the rest will be gallery.

I tried to use lodash to accomplish my goal like that :

```
vm.products.forEach(function(item) {
          _.map(_.sortBy(item.images, 'type'), 'main');
        });
```

but it didn't work.

i also tried to use this :

```
var data = _.sortBy(vm.products[0].images, ['type', 'desc']).reverse();
```

but it took only the first object.

`vm.products` is the main array object container

Comment: it seems you're not asking for a sort but a modification of the existing array.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes exactly i am trying to modify the existing array. So then the result i will assign it to my view model object.

Comment: It also seems that you switched id in your example. Is that mistake or wanted modification?

Comment: I assumed that was a mistake, but if it was intended then my answer is incorrect and I don't understand the question.

Comment: @bigless yes it is a mistake id is not a problem for me. i just want to find away to sort every item in the array which has an array images and for every image i want the one type main to be first.

Comment: i have improved my question to make it easier understanding for the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below does what you want.  Most importantly the nested map statements.  you could extract those functions out and give them names appropriate to your domain such as 'sanitizeImages' or something.

```js
const data = getData(),
  expectedResult = getExpectedResult();

const result = _.map(data, obj => {
  obj.images = _.map(obj.images, (imageObj, idx) => {
    imageObj.type = (idx === 0)
      ? 'main'
      : 'gallery';
      
    return imageObj;
  });
  
  return obj;
});

document.getElementById('result').textContent = _.isEqual(result, expectedResult)
  ? 'passed'
  : 'failed'


// helper functions

function getData() {
  return [
    {
      id: "1",
      images: [
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (2).png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:31"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM.png",
          type: "main",
          $$hashKey: "object:32"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      images: [
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (2).png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:31"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM.png",
          type: "main",
          $$hashKey: "object:32"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (3).png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:33"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}

function getExpectedResult() {
  return [
    {
      id: "1",
      images: [
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (2).png",
          type: "main",
          $$hashKey: "object:31"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM.png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:32"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      images: [
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (2).png",
          type: "main",
          $$hashKey: "object:31"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM.png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:32"
        },
        {
          filename: "Screen Shot 2018-01-25 at 10.14.48 AM (3).png",
          type: "gallery",
          $$hashKey: "object:33"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="result"></h3>
```